# Where is a mature library of "fragile" list operations for Haskell?

Tags: list, haskell

I'm driven to ask this question after several years of littering libraries with definitions like this:

```
fragileZip :: [t1] -> [t2] -> [(t1, t2)]
fragileZip a b = loop a b
  where
    loop [] []           = []
    loop (h1:t1) (h2:t2) = (h1,h2) : loop t1 t2
    loop _ _             = error "fragileZip: lists were not the same length."
```

My experience is that the decisions made in the Haskell prelude -- regarding `take`, `drop`, `zip`, etc not erroring upon insufficient elements -- allow cute tricks with infinite lists, and can be convenient in certain circumstances, but are devious sources of silent failures, when, for example, zipping lists that are expected to be the same length.

Does anybody know of a full `Data.List` replacement that tries to be "fragile" like the above zip, always throwing an error if expectations are not met: if list lengths don't match, or if there are not enough elements?

[Footnotes: yes, it would be good to program with total functions, but that means discharging the relevant proof obligations with type-level information, not masking errors by returning bad values!  Standard zip quietly dropping data can be just such a silent failure.  Also, I don't care how the error results are communicated (exception, Maybe, or Either).  I'll take anything if there is an existing hackage lib that fits the bill!]

Comment: A lot of haskell users don't like errors.  So something more haskell-esque would be `zip :: [a] -> [b] -> Maybe [(a,b)]`.

Comment: That would be fine too, but the existing conventions of `Data.List` does include a number of error-throwing functions like (!!).  There would also be some incentive for a drop-in replacement to retain the same types.

Comment: You might like the [these](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/these) package for this specific need -- specifically [Data.Align](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/these-0.4.1/docs/Data-Align.html).

Answer (score 4):

The [`safe`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/safe-0.3.4/docs/Safe.html) package contains "safer" versions of many functions from the `Prelude`; they do not throw errors and instead return `Maybe` values on failure. You will still be detecting the error at runtime, though.

The [`errors`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/errors) package re-exports the functions from `safe` and adds other convenience functions for error-handling.

If you are willing to dive into the newer, dependent-type like features of Haskell, the `sized-vector` package offers list whose size is checked at compile-time. In particular, there's the [`zipSame`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/sized-vector-1.3.1.1/docs/Data-Vector-Sized.html) function that only zips lists with the same length:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}

import Data.Vector.Sized
import Data.Type.Natural

vec2 :: Vector Char Two
vec2 = 'a' :- 'b' :- Nil

vec3 :: Vector Char Three
vec3 = 'x' :- 'y' :- 'z' :- Nil

vecZipped = zipSame vec2 vec3
```

This code fails at compile time with the error:

```
Couldn't match type 'S Zero with 'Z
Expected type: Vector Char Two
  Actual type: Vector Char Three
In the second argument of `zipSame', namely `vec3'
In the expression: zipSame vec2 vec3
In an equation for `vecZipped': vecZipped = zipSame vec2 vec3
```

See [here](https://www.fpcomplete.com/user/konn/prove-your-haskell-for-great-safety/dependent-types-in-haskell) for a tutorial for `sized-vector` and dependent types on Haskell. The [comments](http://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/1z8wsv/prove_your_haskell_for_great_safety_part_i/) also have useful information.

(Sometimes zipping lists of different sizes is what you want, however. I often zip finite lists with infinite ones, because the latter are easier to define.)

Answer (score 3):

I think what you are asking goes against the philosophy of Haskell. Code involving `error` or any other runtime crashes isn't good for valid reasons.

But obviously, you can create a wrapper around itself if you want:

```
fragileZip :: [a] -> [b] -> [(a,b)]
fragileZip x y = if length x == length y
                 then zip x y
                 else error "Not of the same length"
```

If you really want to showcase some error in the result type, then use the type `Maybe` or `Either` for that. Example:

```
fragileZip :: [a] -> [b] -> Maybe [(a,b)]
fragileZip x y = if length x == length y
                 then Just $ zip x y
                 else Nothing
```

Comment: Well, we want to turn our partial functions total by discharging the relevant proof obligations, not by just returning *something* (https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat) ;-).

Comment: Also, FYI, those two definitions above traverse the list three times rather than one and lose the ability to process large lists in a stream-like way (which is another sometimes-questionable use of lists, hence the lazy IO debate and pipes/conduit libraries).

Comment: Sorry, in that case I don't think I know of any libraries doing that. Maybe you can create and put them on Hackage. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your zip can be found as `pair` in the [list-extras](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/list-extras-0.4.1.1/docs/Data-List-Extras-Pair.html) package. There is also the [safe](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/safe) package, though it addresses `head`, `tail` and their error-throwing ilk, rather than `zip`, `drop`, etc.

Comment: I'm surprised that `pair` returns `Maybe [(a,b)]` - among other things, this can't work at all on infinite lists. Surely it would be better to return `[Maybe (a,b)]`, and let the caller use `sequence` if they want to know before even starting to process the zipped list whether the sizes were the same?

Comment: `sequence` wouldn't help with two infinite lists, whereas if just one list is infinite `pair` works fine. A more subtle issue is that an implementation which made `take 100 $ pair [1..] [1..]` feasible would also allow `take 100 $ pair [1..100] [1..200]`, which might be a little surprising.